# Apply ajaxForm on IE

Tags: ajaxform

I'm trying to make this code work for IE(Any of them),
The code work on other browsers..

it is possible to make the function AjaxForm work on Internet Explorer?
Because I have search on the internet and i did not found nothing that help me solve this problem.

Here is the Code:

```
$('form#upload').ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $('div.status').html('<img src="loading.gif" alt="" />');
    },
    success: function(callback) {
        if(callback.match(/(.*):::ok/i)){
            $("form#upload").hide();
            $("div.status").html(callback);
        }
        else{
            alert("Error occurd!");
        }                            
    }
});
```